# Looking to add auto-play and touch-swipe to Image Slider

Tags: javascript, java, web

I've built my website from scratch, and the image slider on the homepage is exactly how I want it - visually. It's the right size, it's responsive (resizes accurately, buttons in place), and the radio buttons and slider arrows are just how I want them.

THE PROBLEM: I am looking to add auto-play to the slideshow so that the slides alternate on a timer;

AND

I also want to add touch-swipe so that the slider reacts to touch on mobile devices.

I'm terrible with JavaScript, and spent hours making the current slider, even with a tutorial.

Would someone be able to help me include these functions to the slider?

My website is [www.wildsidecocktails.co.uk](http://www.wildsidecocktails.co.uk)

The JavaScript (which includes the functions for the menu on mobile devices) is:

```
var slidePosition = 1;
SlideShow(slidePosition);

function plusSlides(n) {
  SlideShow(slidePosition += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  SlideShow(slidePosition = n);
}

function SlideShow(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("Containers");
  var circles = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  if (n > slides.length) {slidePosition = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slidePosition = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].className = circles[i].className.replace(" enable", "");
  }
  slides[slidePosition-1].style.display = "block";
  circles[slidePosition-1].className += " enable";
}
```

I've tried watching tutorials and guides teaching how to add autoplay, and others teaching how to add touch-sensitivity, but none of them seem exclusively Vanilla script, or are hard to integrate with the current slider setup.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic Implementation

So to give you the rough idea on how to achieve this, your slideshow will basically have a container div that will contain all the images that's going to be shown right? for now i've used divs for the sake of simplicity, in your example you can have images inside of the child divs with width and height set accordingly to fill the slideshow container

So we need to stack all these images on top of each other instead of each image taking a new line or space, for that we use the `position` attribute. we make the parent container of position type `relative` and every images in it will have a position type of `absolute` so it'll stack on top of each other

now how the slideshow will work is by initially setting the opacity of all the elements to 0, we iterate through each element and change the opacity back to 100% so it will be visible, once the frame passes we set the opacity back to a 0 so it will be invisible.

We can make this iteration process possible by using `setInterval` function

i have not included the buttons for navigation in this, you can do it simply by adding two buttons and manipulate the `index` variable to increment or decrement the position based on button click event

also you can temporarily pause the auto slideshow on button clicks by using:

```
let slideShowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 1000);
clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
```

and then after a certain timeout you can resume it by calling the same function again. i'll leave that to you

You can tweak the slideshow speed by setting the interval timer in millisecond, in this example i used 2 second delay so that will be 2 * 1000 = 2000 ms

```js
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');
let index = 1;


function slideshow() {
    // reset slide index counter if it exceeds the maximum limit
    if (index >= slides.length) index = 0;
    
    // show the current slide
    if (!slides[index].classList.contains('show'))
        slides[index].classList.add('show');

    // hide the previous slide, only if index is > 0
    if (index > 0 && slides[index - 1].classList.contains('show'))
        slides[index - 1].classList.remove('show');
    // if index is 0 or less it means the slideshow has restarted so hide the last element which is at the end of the container array    
    else if (index <= 0 && slides[slides.length - 1].classList.contains('show'))
        slides[slides.length - 1].classList.remove('show');

    index++;
}

setInterval(slideshow, 2000);
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.slides {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slides show" style="background-color: yellow">slide 1</div>
    <div class="slides" style = "background-color: red">slide 2</div>
    <div class="slides" style = "background-color: blue">slide 3</div>
</div>
```